# Create html table from array from ajax response

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, laravel

In my Laravel app, I add ajax query (which work after pressed button). I get the result in ajax, I see it on console (it's array).
But I need to send an answer from js to PHP for creating a table

This is code of input:

```html
<input type="text" name="check" id="check">
```

This is code of button:

```html
<button type="button" class="check-client btn btn-success">Find</button>
```

This is code of ajax (JS):

```
$(document).on("click", ".check-client", function () {
    const data = $("#check").val();

    $.ajax({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            'data': data
        },
        url: '/checkValues',
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
            const dataForTable = result;
        }
    });
});
```

For creating table I try to do this:

send response to php+html:

```
$(".testClass").append(result);
```

get this value:

```html
<div class="testClass"></div>
```

and create a table, using foreach:

```html
<div class="testClass"></div>
<table class="table table-bordered text-center">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">ID</th>
            <th scope="col">Person</th>
            <th scope="col">Cost</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      @foreach($dataForTable as $item)
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">$item['id']</th>
          <td>$item['person']</td>
          <td>$item['cost']</td>
        </tr>
      @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

So, it doesn't work. How to create a table from ajax response?

Comment: What is in your ajax response?

Comment: @Will, ```date: [{id: 1, person: 'Jack', cost: '12'}, {id: 2, person: 'Kate', cost: '15'}]```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you trying to run jQuery at the client side to uses the return of ajax request (**dataForTable**) at the server side, it's out of PHP context server. PHP works only server side, meanwhile jQuery is working on browser client, if you want to run javascript in the server side you have to search for other technology, like  Node, look at [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/).

Wether you want to update a table on client side using ajax request you have to update a table iterate de variable (**dataForTable**) on client side, after the request, like this:

```
$.getJSON( "ajax/test.json", function( data ) {
  var items = [];
  $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
    items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>" );
  });

$( "<ul/>", {
    "class": "my-new-list",
    html: items.join( "" )
  }).appendTo( "body" );
});
```

There are many other examples like this above in [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/).

Finally, you have to work at Client side wether you want to use jQuery, or work at server side using the PHP helpers.